# File upload issue in Struts2 - Source must not be null

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, file-upload, struts2

I am trying to implement a file upload functionality in using struts 2. But I get the error "Source must not be null".When I debug the code the source(uploaded) File data appears to be null.

Following is my code,

**add_categories.jsp**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <section class="col-xs-12">
        <form action="addCategory" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="categoryName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="categoryName" name="categoryName"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="categoryDescription" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Description</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea id="categoryDescription" name="categoryDescription" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="categoryImage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" id="categoryImage" name="categoryImage" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

**struts.xml**

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>

    <package name="admin" namespace="/admin" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="viewCategories" class="org.miraj.javabrains.actions.CategoryAction" method="viewCategories">
            <result name="success">/view_categories.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="addCategories">
            <result>/add_categories.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="addCategory" class="org.miraj.javabrains.actions.CategoryAction">
            <!--<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>-->
            <!--<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">-->
                <!--<param name="allowedTypes">application/ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg</param>-->
            <!--</interceptor-ref>-->
            <result name="success">/add_category_success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/add_category_failure.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

....

**CategoryAction.java**

```
public class CategoryAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Category> {

Category category=new Category();
private String categoryError;
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
AdminServices adminServices=context.getBean("adminServices",AdminServices.class);
List<Category> categories;

//file upload handling
private File categoryImage;
private String categoryImageContentType;
private String categoryImageFileName;
private String destPath;



public String execute()
{
    category.setReg_date(new Date());
    if (adminServices.category_exists(category.getCategoryName())) {

        setCategoryError("The Category already exists");
        return "failure";
    }
    else
    {
        destPath="../uploads/";
        try{


            File destFile  = new File(destPath, categoryImageFileName);
            FileUtils.copyFile(categoryImage, destFile);

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "failure";
        }
        adminServices.addCategory(category);
        return "success";

    }
}
```

...

**Category.java**

```
package org.miraj.javabrains.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;


@Entity
@Table (schema = "HIBERNATE")

public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String categoryName;
private String categoryDescription;
private String categoryImage;
private Date reg_date;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryId",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Item> categoryItems=new ArrayList<Item>();



public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String name) {
    this.categoryName = name;
}

public String getCategoryDescription() {
    return categoryDescription;
}

public void setCategoryDescription(String description) {
    this.categoryDescription = description;
}

public Date getReg_date() {
    return reg_date;
}

public void setReg_date(Date reg_date) {
    this.reg_date = reg_date;
}

public void addCategoryItem(Item item)
{
 categoryItems.add(item);
}

public String getCategoryImage() {
    return categoryImage;
}

public void setCategoryImage(String categoryImage) {
    this.categoryImage = categoryImage;
}
}
```

now, when I upload an image I get values for 
categoryImageContentType,
categoryImageFileName

But, categoryImage is null and causes the error.

Any help is much appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: String categoryImage is suspect :)

Comment: Thanks @AndreaLigios, you saved the day ;)

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Change the type of **`categoryImage`** from **`String`** to **`File`**

**2.** I have a doubt on the type, you are using to save the category image.

Check the type of the Category Image column in your Database. Is it **`tinyblob`** ?. If it is then change it to **`longblob`** & retry to save the image.
If possible then post your hibernate mapping code too.

Comment: yes you're right, The problem was that I used the same name categoryImage in the model and also in the jsp. I don't want to save the image in the database, but only the name(which I'll use to refer to the image when I fetch it later), so I used a String variable in the model.

But since in the jsp and in the Action class it's of type File and since this is a model driven structure this issue occurs. I changed the variable name in the model and assigned categoryImageFileName to it. Then I got the real file value for the categoryImage in the action class.